# Understanding "Herberts"

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang, irish-english

This passage is from The Ferryman (jez Butterworth) What "Herberts" means?

MAGENNIS. When I was a kid we used to go out to my grandfather’s place
down in Fermanagh there, and help with the harvest. It was good craic.
Got us out the smoke. Out in the fresh air. Harvest time’s a fine time of
the year, so it is.
Pause.
Well, I’ll get straight to it. (Beat.) Three days ago, there’s two turf-cutters
cutting turf in County Louth, just across the border there, when they come
across a body in the bog. (Beat.) Now they’ve read the stories in the press
about prehistoric finds, your Stoneyisland Man, your Tollund Man there,
two thousand years old, and how the people that find them become
famous. They’re hatching all these dreams, TV interviews, prize from the
National Museum and whatnot, when one of ’em spots that your man’s
wearing a pair of Gola trainers. A Timex wristwatch. Brown corduroys.
(Beat.) So they rummage through his pockets and they find his car keys.
His last pay packet from December 1971. Some Polos. A betting slip
signed on the back by Georgie Best. A picture of his wee’un. (Beat.) So
your two Herberts there call the Garda, and they run a quick check of
your man’s dental records, and they come up with a name.

Comment: Pretty sure it's slang as my Dad used to use. More info [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37663/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-herbert-in-british-slang)

Comment: I've never heard it without a (usually derogatory) qualifier, typically _spotty herbert_. Looking in the GloWbE corpus for "(adjective) Herberts" gives me just 11 hits - 10 GB and 1 Irish (I've removed one which referred to a family called Herbert). The adjectives are _young, thick, creative, little, fashionable, spotty,_ and _ordinary,_ . Only "creative" is appreciative ("fashionable" is not complimentary in the context).

Comment: I don't know if this is a set text for some course,  but you've got yourself a very hard play to understand word by word.  Very few native speakers of English will know all the 1980s Irish slang that this book uses.  Please don't try to understand every word, that's impossible.  Instead try to enjoy it as a whole.  And please don't use this as a model of how English should be spoken.  Part of the experience is being in a foreign culture where you don't know all the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Herbert**](https://definedictionarymeaning.com/topic/119254/herbert) - *An undistinguished or foolish man or youth.*

I think it's an exclusively ***British*** usage. Basically, it's just a dismissive / derogatory reference to (unknown, unnamed) ***people***. But unlike near-equivalent terms such as ***Wally, [wise] guy,*** it very rarely occurs in the singular.

Comment: "British" but this speaker is apparently *Irish*.

Comment: Well, I did say *British*, and "The British Isles" includes even *Southern* Ireland! In any case, the author here, [Jeremy "Jez" Butterworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jez_Butterworth) (born March 1969) is an ***English*** playwright, screenwriter, and film director. These days, lots of writers just sprinkle a few ***craics*** in their text and call it "dialectally authentic Irish".

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree.  Calling someone a daft Herbert is colloquial in the North of England.  Just implies a dismissive attitude to a person or persons.  Those daft Herberts who drive without seatbelts are putting their lives at risk.
I haven't seen it used much without an accompanying adjective.