# What does "Some Polos" mean in this passage from "The Ferryman"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

The following is from *The Ferryman*, page 7 (depiction of a man, who was found in the bog, he was supposed to be an IRA informer, but something went wrong and IRA itself they killed him). What does "Some Polos" mean?

Was he wearing it or did they find it in his pockets? Was a typical dress for the IRA volunteers a civil dress? Or do brown corduroys, English brand Gola refer refer to something else? I know that the informers were given some expensive staff in the past and IRA bribed new members.

> "...your man is wearing a pair of Gola trainers. A Timex wristwatch. Brown corduroys. (beat) So the rummage through his pockets and they find his car keys. His last pay packet from December 1971 (his money from the work?) Some Polos (a polo neck, sweater, a polo t-shirt, a headdress, some Polos corporate gift like a pen, some polos crossword puzzle clue?) A betting slip signed by Georgie Best."

Comment: these maybe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polo_(confectionery)

Comment: Undoubtedly Polo mints, and presumably the pay packet from his ordinary job.

Comment: By the way, an IRA informer is someone who informs the police about the IRA.  He would have been killed by the IRA because he was an informer.

Comment: Informers, whether IRA members or not, were called 'touts' by the IRA, and sometimes executed merely on suspicion.

Comment: Actual or suspected informers killed by the IRA were buried in bogs. The Bogside is an urban district of Derry. Many of these, called 'the [Disappeared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappeared_(Northern_Ireland))', were found in bogs or other rural locations decades after being murdered.

Comment: I think *The Ferryman* is a set text.  You would probably benefit from reading all the questions and answers of https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/103409/user103409?tab=questions If I recall, the early parts of the book do tell of a body found in a bog.

Comment: In particular https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250595/understanding-herberts

Comment: “IRA volunteers” is an interesting phrasing. I suppose it’s not inaccurate, but, given their terrorist status, it sounds strange. “Volunteer” generally has positive connotations, which you want to avoid. I’d suggest “members”.

Comment: @Tim "volunteer" is the standard term widely used by both supporters and opponents. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volunteer_(Irish_republican)

Answer (score 7):

Polo mints.  A hard, mint flavoured sweet made in the shape of a ring.

[image]

The IRA, was never a military force like the British army.  It was a resistance movement and a terrorist organisation.  There was no "uniform" of the IRA, except perhaps the balaclavas that were worn to hide their faces.  Gola trainers and corduroys are simply comfortable and fairly inexpensive clothes that any young Irish person could have been wearing in the 1970s. Similarly a Timex watch was a low cost brand of digital watch. And a pay slip is from a regular job (it would be normal for a working-class person to be paid weekly by cheque)

Indeed the only notable thing of value is the autograph of Georgie Best, a famous and very popular football player from Ireland (though he played for Manchester United)

Comment: as i suggested. they are quite common in the UK/Ireland and would be instantly recognizable to a native, which is why they are just described by the brand name

Comment: Advertised as 'the mint with the hole'. UK people would not usually call these things 'candy'. There's even an [unboxing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWYIdTR4HzM) on Youtube.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you.

Comment: "a Timex watch was a low cost brand of digital watch" -- [not in the early 1970s](https://www.pcmag.com/news/the-digital-watch-a-brief-history)! "In 1972, Hamilton introduced the world's first commercial electronic digital wristwatch. It retailed for the pricey sum of $2,100..." The bog-man's Timex was analog, and almost certainly [mechanical (not even quartz)](https://www.hodinkee.com/articles/q-timex): "The first quartz watch from Timex was produced in 1972..."